# Simple SQL Failover Plan? Log shipping? Mirroring?

Tags: sql-server-2005, failover, log-shipping

I have a physical Prod DB Server (SQL05) and now a VM DB Server.  The idea is if the physical machine goes down, we repoint our router (via NAT) to the VM machine.  I am thinking of using Log Shipping to keep the VM DB basically current.

1. Is this the correct way to do it?
2. Should I be looking at another way, mirroring perhaps?
3. We would like the VM DB to be in an usable state at all times (so I think this precludes mirroring)

Any (good) suggestions requested!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use [mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h52hef8%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: To my understanding the VM DB would be in a non R/W state while mirroring.  I could be wrong...

Comment: With log shipping, you're expecting the standby to be in a writable state?

Comment: Yes, that would be prefered.  As I understand it though, it will not be.  (Learning the ins and outs here)

Comment: We have opted for Synchronous Database Mirroring (High-Safety Mode) for our solution.  A lot of the info I was getting was just plain wrong.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179344.aspx for a good explanation of Mirroring and Failover.